# How to get Set-Cookie header from ArcGIS REST services?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, http-headers

When I call an ArcGIS REST service, I get Cache-Control, Etag, Content-Encoding, Content-Type, Transfer-Encoding and Date headers.

But I don't get Set-Cookies header.

Is there a way to get this header? Is there any configuration to make on server side?